# Round 12.01 to 13

Tags: c#

Decimal Value = " 19500.98"

I need to display this value to `TextBox` with rounded off like "19501"

If decimal value = " 19500.43"

then

Value = "19501"

If decimal value comes +1 is add.

Comment: You say that the input is a decimal value, but it looks like a string. Is it a string?

Comment: That's not called "rounding".  Converting 0.0000001 to "1" is calling the glass full when it only has a drop of water in it.  Converting a penny to a dollar can make you a millionaire just by doing it often enough.  Takes well less than a second on a modern machine :)

Answer (score 4):

Just try below code:

```
decimal convertDecimal = decimal.Parse("19500.43", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
decimal ceiling = Math.Ceiling(convertDecimal );
```

For more information:

- [DotnetPerls on Math.Ceiling](http://www.dotnetperls.com/math-ceiling)
- [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zx4t0t48%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Don't you need convert string to decimal?

Answer (score 1):

try this on:

```
decimal value = 1500.98M;
decimal newvalue = Math.Ceiling(value);
```

Comment: That answer was given 10 minutes ago already. Also, it doesn't use the textbox as in the question.